# On click photo change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I would like to create a function where I can choose from a few photo's and if I click on one, it should change in the big frame which is also shown (photo).

I think I might messed up the selectors.

**HTML**

```
<div id="photo">
    <img src="http://hd.highresolution-wallpapers.net/wallpapers/space_dimesional_sun-600x800.jpg" alt="Space" />
</div>
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="http://hd.highresolution-wallpapers.net/wallpapers/space_dimesional_sun-600x800.jpg"><img src="http://hd.highresolution-wallpapers.net/wallpapers/space_dimesional_sun-600x800.jpg" alt="Space" /></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSh_AgoWSwWBYuvqlbD7kzIrtcPRCV3jGzn5H4fosJRba8JzE1-Ow"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSh_AgoWSwWBYuvqlbD7kzIrtcPRCV3jGzn5H4fosJRba8JzE1-Ow" alt="Grass" /></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://sitch.org/sailing/images/2006-11-17__sun__600_800.jpg"><img src="http://sitch.org/sailing/images/2006-11-17__sun__600_800.jpg" alt="Water" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.selected').fadeIn();
$("#gallery ul li").on("click", function () {
    var selector = '#gallery ul li[src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]';

    $(".selected").hide();

    $("#gallery ul li").fadeIn();
    return false;
});

$('#gallery ul li img').on('click', function () {
    $(".selected").hide();
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (next.length > 0) {
        next.fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.selected').fadeIn();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You probably don't need to be reinventing the wheel here, as there are many plugins/snippets out there to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

You messed up a lot of things. First off you never show the clicked photo in the frame. Second, when you click on a photo which is inside of an anchor, it will take you to the href of the anchor by default (you would need to add e.preventDefault() to prevent that, also make sure you pass the e parameter in the on click function - function(e)

Html

```
<div id="photo">
        <img src="http://hd.highresolution-wallpapers.net/wallpapers/space_dimesional_sun-600x800.jpg" alt="Space"/>
    </div>
<div id="gallery">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected"><img src="http://hd.highresolution-wallpapers.net/wallpapers/space_dimesional_sun-600x800.jpg" alt="Space" /></li>
            <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSh_AgoWSwWBYuvqlbD7kzIrtcPRCV3jGzn5H4fosJRba8JzE1-Ow" alt="Grass" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sitch.org/sailing/images/2006-11-17__sun__600_800.jpg" alt="Water" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#gallery img', function() {
    $('#photo').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: This answer seems right, but I'd do in the first line just: 
`$('#gallery img').click(function() {` instead of yours. Besides, a method for changing the `class = "selected"` to the new one would probably help the OP a lot.

Comment: if he includes the javascript before the html is parsed, the event won't trigger, for safety measures, I always use the on. event

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the `$('#gallery ul li img').on('click', function (){...}` part:

```
$('#photo').find('img').prop('src',$(this).prop('src'));
```

Final result:

```
$('#gallery ul li img').on('click', function () {
    $(".selected").hide();
    $('#photo').find('img').prop('src',$(this).prop('src'));

    window.location.href="#photo";
    return false;
});
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c7vpJ/3/)